# If every subspace of V is T-invariant, prove that T is a multiple of the identity map.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose V is a vector space and T is a linear transformation. If every subspace of V is T-invariant, prove that T is a scalar multiple of the identity map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $0\ne v\in V$. Then $kv$ is $T$-invariant, hence $Tv=a_v v$ for some $a_v\in k$.
Then for any multiple $w\in kv$, clearly $Tw=a_vv$ as well.
Likewise, if $w\in V\setminus kv$ we obtain $Tw = c_ww$ and $T(v+w)=c_{v+w}(v+w)$ with $c_w,c_{v+w}\in k$.
From $T(v+w)=Tv+Tw$ we infer
$$c_{v+w}(v+w)=c_vv+c_ww $$
i.e. 
$$(c_{v+w}-c_v)v + (c_{v+w}-c_w)w=0.$$
Now  $v,w$ are *linearly independant*, so that we conclude $c_{v+w}=c_v=c_w$. In other words, $Tx=c_vx$ for all $x\in V$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $Tw = a_v w$? And given that you use $c_v$ further down, maybe you want to change $a_v$ into $c_v$ at the beginning? Or am misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: Hello? I think your answer contains a few typos.