# $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{\log 7x}$?

Tags: limits

I did l'Hospital's rule and I got

$\dfrac{1}{x}/\dfrac{7}{7x} = \dfrac{0}{0}$ (after "plugging" $\infty$ in)

But is that the answer? I dont think $\frac{0}{0}$ is an answer. Or is it the answer and that means the limit is divergent.

Comment: Try cancelling the x's

Comment: And what do you mean by "plugging infinity in"?

Comment: @MatthewLevy OMG THANK U SO MUCH, the answer is one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln x}{\ln7x}$$

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln x}{\ln7x}$ as you it goes to in determinant, so L'Hopital's rule gives $$\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{7}{7x}}=\frac{7x}{7x}=1$$

i.e., the limit value is 1

Answer (score 5):

To properly exploit L'hopital's rule, one must know the limit exists; see [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).  Here we kill two birds with one stone, showing that there is a limit and that it is $1$, without using L'hopital or derivatives:

For $x > 1$, $\ln x > 0$, whence we can say:

$\dfrac{\ln x}{\ln 7x} = \dfrac{\ln x}{\ln x + \ln7} = \dfrac{1}{1 + \dfrac{\ln7}{\ln x}} \to 1 \tag{1}$

as $\ln x \to \infty$.  As $x \to \infty$, $\ln x \to \infty$, and so . . . 
***voila!***, followeth (1)!

Comment: I think you want a log on $7$.

Comment: Thanks to Cameron Williams, dh87 and any other editors for pointing this out!  Typing too fast . . . Cheers!

Comment: I feel somewhat uncomfortable that this solution was not signed off with the usual "Fiat Lux!!!"

Comment: @JessicaK:  Me too.  ***Fiat Lux!!!*** etc. incurred the displeasure of at least one moderator and other "authorities", so I somewhat ruefully ceased using it.  I am still corresponding with said "authorities" on this.  For more, see the comment streams to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090362/if-every-vector-is-an-eigenvector-the-operator-must-be-a-scalar-multiple-of-the, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208587/if-r-is-a-pid-is-it-true-that-r-ker-phi-is-also-a-pid . . . continued

Comment: @JessicaK:  (continuation) and the meta thread http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/14999/how-to-deal-with-users-padding-their-answers-with-custom-signatures . . . in the meantime, thanks for your concern and, as ever, ***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

Something else to note, using property of logs, we have $\log (7x)=\log(7) +\log (x)$.   So your fraction can be rewritten as

$\frac {\log x}{\log x +\log 7}$.  Since $\log 7$ is constant,  as $x\to \infty$, we have $\log x \to \infty$,  so the tiny increase is meaningless, thus a limit of 1.   Formally, you'd still probably use L'Hospitals as above.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be hasty to put the x value too soon:
$$\require{cancel}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln x}{\ln 7x}\stackrel{\rm L'Hos.}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{\cancel{\color{blue}x}}}{\frac{1}{\cancel{\color{red}7}\cancel{\color{blue}x}}.\cancel{\color{red}7}}=1$$
where I have used the chain rule for log7x.